# Вытащить заранее неопределеннй ключ в обьекте

Tags: javascript

Привет. Нужно ключи(заранее неизвесто значение и к-во) в обькте в масив. Подскажите плиз, как можно реализовать.. Пример обьекта:

{name: "itrParent",
    value: {
        "key0": [

```
        {
            "name": "itrChild",
            "value": {
                "key0": [
                    {
                        "name": "tp1",
                        "value": "Россия6575"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "tp2",
                        "value": "75675"
                    },
                ],
```

//                      .....

```
                "keyN": [
                    {
                        "name": "tp1",
                        "value": "Россия6575"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "tp2",
                        "value": "75675"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "anyUserInfoInChild",
                        "value": "anyUserInfo value 1"
                    },
                ]
            }
        }

    ],
}
```

}

Comment: а не легче:

    itrChild": {
                "key0": [
                    {
                        "tp1": "Россия6575"
                    },
                    {
                        "tp2": "75675"
                    },
                ],
    ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно обойти объект используя for..in и сохранить все ключи

```
var keys = [];
for(var key in object) 
{
    keys.push(key);
}
```

Comment: [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)